# Can't use saved information to load into an array

Tags: c#, arrays, file, split, save

I've managed to save some information into a file. I want to be able to read that information and use it to create an item

```
public void Save()
{            
   StreamWriter writer;
   writer = new StreamWriter("PlayerInventory.txt");
   for (int i = 0; i < playerInventory.Length; i++)
   {
      if (playerInventory[i] != null)
      {
         if (playerInventory[i] is Sheild sheild)
         {
            writer.WriteLine("Sheild:" + sheild.Defence + "," + sheild.name + "," + sheild.description + "," + sheild.cost);
         }
      }     
   }
   else
   {}
}
```

I started using this code to load it but i don't know how to finish the code. Right now its split but i don't know how to assign it to anything.

**For example** sheild:20,Shield,this is a shield,100

Right now that's split into

1. 20,
2. Shield,
3. this is a shield,
4. 100

But I don't know who to assign those stuff to an array

```
public void Load()
{
   StreamReader reader;
   reader = new StreamReader("PlayerInventory.txt");
   string line;
   string[] currentLineData;

   while (true)
   {
      try
      {
         line = reader.ReadLine();
         if (line == null)
         {
            break;
         }
         if (line.Contains("Sheild"))
         {
            line.Replace("Sheild:", "");
            currentLineData = line.Split(',');
         }
      } 
      catch
      {
         break;
      }
}
reader.Close();}
```

Comment: Hi, interesting, was there an exception or error perhaps?

Comment: Maybe a typo -- "sheild" vs "shield"...

Comment: its more of that i dont know what code to use to get the information place the information into an array and thx for the typos :)

Comment: `but i cant think of a way to get it to work` what does that mean, really? do you get an error?

Comment: Any particular reason you don't want to go with a flow and just use JSON to store data? If you want help with your code please review [MCVE] guidance on posting code - we can't help you if code in the post simply *somewhat represents* code you want and does not compile/reproduce errors you are seeing in your actual code.

Comment: You need to create an array or List of Shield. Create object of Shield class in the loop. Assign values to it's properties from the file. Add that object to the list. That's how you do it.

Comment: It seems you want a list of all those arrays you are creating, like a `List<string[]>`. Once you create an instance of it, you can add: `list.Add(currentLineData);`.

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are designing a game.

If I were setting up an inventory that included a shield with stats, I'd look at creating a complex data type, using a "struct" for an inventory item.

Then I'd create an array of the inventory struct items, with one for each inventory slot - before loading my file in.

This could hold all the different info you need for any item that can be stored in inventory like Item Name, defense strength, attack strength etc.

Then, when you load your file in, all the right stuff will be in places with nice names etc. for you to easily find them later.

If you need an extra stat, add a row to your struct definition, then add a column to your file and you are ready to go.